# mysql limit by views but order alphabeticly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like that I want to take the 20 most hit singers and order them (these 20 singers) alphabeticly.

```
   id    name         hit
    ----------------
    1     Beyonce      2540
    2     Eminem       1432
    3     Pink         1642
    4     Shakira      1234
    .
    .
```

For example I use this code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_categories ORDER BY hit DESC limit 20");
```

I take the 20 with the most hits, but I want to also order them alphabeticly.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM pm_categories
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM pm_categories
  ORDER BY hit DESC
  LIMIT 20
) ORDER BY name
```

You need to query based on the hits separately, and then use the ids of the top 20 to query and sort by name.

Since you have an older version of mysql, you will need to do a join instead.

```
SELECT cat.*
FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM pm_categories
  ORDER BY hit DESC
  LIMIT 20
) top_hits
JOIN pm_categories cat ON top_hits.id = cat.id
ORDER BY cat.name
```

Comment: It gives error:                                                                   Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/admin/domains/xxx.com/public_html/melody/include/functions.php on line 413

Comment: That means that mysql_query had an error. Print out the results of mysql_error() to see what the error is. As @Inca said, you could have an old version of mysql.

Comment: I have the version MySQL 5.1.57, I think it is not the old one?

Comment: """This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"""                                      So which version shall I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_categories ORDER BY hit DESC, name ASC limit 20");
```